# Create-react-app command doesn't use ES6 classes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to learn React and am following a few tutorials. When I run the `create-react-app` command from my terminal however, my App.js file is not the ES6 version that I see with tutorials. Instead it contains the following:

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Learn React
        </a>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

instead of the ES6 style syntax...

```
class App extends React.Component {
  //...
}
```

Why is this and how can I change it so that when I run the command to create an app it automatically creates a more up-to-date version?

Thank you

Comment: Using classes does not make app more up to date.  In fact, [react hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html#hooks-and-function-components) are only available to function components.

Comment: Functions and classes are both valid/up-to-date ways to write components. The only way that is deprecated is `React.createClass`.

Comment: Further to @zero298 's comment, I believe that the code you have is in face more up to date than the example with the class syntax

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Functional components are peers with class-based components. Neither is more up-to-date than the other (hooks aside). Functional components are getting used much more often than they used to be, though, thanks to [hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html). (In fact, since hooks can't be used with class-based components, there might be an argument that functional components have access to newer features than class-based ones do...)

Looking at `create-react-app`'s command-line switches, it doesn't look like it has an option to create a class-based `App` component for you. But of course, it's a small change to make immediately after creating the app, if you prefer it be a class-based component. You just edit the `App.js` (or `App.tsx`) file.

Answer (score 1):

**Create React App 2.0**

I have used the following command which works for me. I have passed the react-scrips version also.

**npx**

```
npx create-react-app my-app --scripts-version=react-scripts@2.0
```

**npm**

```
npm init react-app my-app --scripts-version=react-scripts@2.0
```

[Create React App 2.0: Babel 7, Sass, and More](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/10/01/create-react-app-v2.html)